# Laravel 5.3, Ajax post 500 error

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I've been trying to get my POST to work but nothing is really working. I got my UPDATE and DELETE to work, but I'm still getting 500 errors when I'm trying to post something.

I already have my CSRF-TOKEN on top of my file.

```
//create new task / update existing task
$("#btn-save").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    var formData = {
        task: $('#task').val(),
        description: $('#description').val(),
    }

    //used to determine the http verb to use [add=POST], [update=PUT]
    var state = $('#btn-save').val();

    var type = "POST"; //for creating new resource
    var task_id = $('#task_id').val();;
    var my_url = url;

    if (state == "update"){
        type = "PUT"; //for updating existing resource
        my_url += '/' + task_id;
    }

    console.log(formData);

    $.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: my_url,
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data){
            console.log(data);

            var task = '<tr id="task' + data.id + '"><td>' + data.task + '</td><td>' + data.description + '</td><td>' + data.created_at + '</td><td>' + data.done + '</td>';
            task += '<td><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs btn-detail open-modal" value="' + data.id + '">Bewerk</button>';
            task += '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete delete-task" value="' + data.id + '">Verwijder</button></td></tr>';

            if (state == "add"){ //if user added a new record
                $('#tasks-list').append(task);
            }else{ //if user updated an existing record

                $("#task" + task_id).replaceWith( task );
            }

            $('#frmTasks').trigger("reset");

            $('#myModal').modal('hide')
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: The 500 error would come from your PHP code, not the javascript code listed here. Check your error logs to find out why it's throwing a 500.

Comment: Error 500 seems like permission error. Try to check the permission of your files.

Comment: Can you post your Laravel code, including the routes where you define these URI?

Comment: Where do you set the url in your JavaScript?

Comment: @hogan In my ajax-crud.js:

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
    }) 
    var url = '/tasks';

Comment: ok, what does your storage/logs/laravel.log say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

500 means its an internal server error, so something in your php is wrong.

Open your storage/logs/laravel.log and go to your last error. That gives you a clue what the problem is.

(If you have `APP_DEBUG=true` in your .env, then you should also be able to inspect the error response in the browser.)

Comment: It said that one of my rows in a table didn't have a default value. Strange that something like that messes up everything.